# How can I authenticate users in phpunit Testing using Passport

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.6

I am trying to write a PHPUnit test that authenticates a user first before allowing the user to make a post request but got the error

> 1) Tests\Feature\BooksTest::test_onlyAuthenticatedUserCanAddBookSuccessfully
>   ErrorException: Trying to get property 'client' of non-object
>
> C:\wamp64\www\bookstore\vendor\laravel\passport\src\ClientRepository.php:89
>   C:\wamp64\www\bookstore\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php:71
>   C:\wamp64\www\bookstore\vendor\laravel\passport\src\HasApiTokens.php:67
>   C:\wamp64\www\bookstore\tests\Feature\BooksTest.php:20

When I run my BooksTest

```
public function test_onlyAuthenticatedUserCanAddBookSuccessfully()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $token = $user->createToken('bookbook')->accessToken;

    $response = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token])
        ->json('POST', '/api/books', [
            'title' => 'new book post',
            'author' => 'new author',
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);

    $response->assertStatus(201);
}
```

It's my first time working with PHPUnit test, and I have no idea why I'm getting this error. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Passport::actingAs` to accomplish this.

For example:

```
public function test_onlyAuthenticatedUserCanAddBookSuccessfully()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    Passport::actingAs($user);

    $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/books', [
            'title' => 'new book post',
            'author' => 'new author',
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);

    $response->assertStatus(201);
}
```

See the documentation here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#testing

Comment: Got an error `ErrorException: Undefined variable: user` from the line where I am setting the `user_id` But if I hard code it, the test is passed. How can i use the id of the created user instead of hard coding a value?

Comment: Just assign the response from the factory to a variable. See my updated answer.

Comment: You're also can use `$this->actingAs($user, 'api')` to create authentication using passport. This solution only works if you're using Laravel Passport as default API Authentication.